# (simplified further) Is Brascamp-Lieb inequality on the sphere applicable for these functions for some $1\leq p<2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, geometric-inequalities

My question is on Brascamp-Lieb-inequality on the Euclidean  sphere (which can be viewed as an analogue of Young's inequality on the sphere) obtained in [1].

(See also this question:
[Brascamp-Lieb inequalities on the sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325211/brascamp-lieb-inequalities-on-the-sphere) )

The inequality reads:

Let $e_{i},i=1,\dots,N$, be orthogonal vectors in
$\mathbb{R}^{N}$. If  $f_j$ are positive functions on $[-1,1]$, $N \geq 3$, and $p\geq 2$ then
$$
\int_{S^{N-1}} \prod_{j=1}^N f_j(x\cdot e_j)  d\mu(x)
\leq \prod_{j=1}^N \left(\int_{S^{N-1}} f_j(x\cdot e_j)^p d\mu(x)\right)^{1/p},
$$
where $\mu$ is the uniform Borel probability measure on the sphere $S^{N-1}$.

Fix **$(x_{1},\dots,x_{N})\in \mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus S^{N-1}$**. Let  $0<\alpha_{j}<1$. Suppose that
$$f_{j}(t)=|t-x_{j}|^{-\alpha_{j}},\quad x_{i}\neq x_{j},\;\forall i\neq j.$$
Does the inequality $(1)$ hold true for these particular functions $f_{j}$ **for some $1\leq p<2$** ?

That is, is it true that

$$
\int_{S^{N-1}} \prod_{j=1}^N 
|\theta\cdot e_j-x_{j}|^{-\alpha_{j}}
 d\mu(\theta)
 \leq C\prod_{j=1}^N \left(\int_{S^{N-1}} |\theta\cdot e_j-x_{j}|^{-p\alpha_{j}}
 d\mu(\theta)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\qquad (*)$$
for some $1\leq p<2$ ?

[1] EA Carlen, EH Lieb, and M Loss.  "A Sharp Analogue of Young's Inequality on $S^N$ and Related Entropy Inequalities."  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408030

Edit Summary:

As @fedja pointed out, the estimate is immediately false when
$(x_{1},\dots, x_{N})$ lies on $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$.

Latest Edit:

Instead of asking whether the inequality $(*)$ holds with $p=1$ I tried to simplify the question to whether $(*)$ is true for some $p\in [1,2[$.

**Most recent Edit**:
Simplified the functions $f_{j}$ to $f_{j}(t):=|t-x_{j}|^{-\alpha_{j}}$ instead of $f_{j}(t)=|t^k-x_{j}|^{-\alpha_{j}}$ where $k$ is an odd integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to the question as stated is "No" even if $N=2$. Let $k=1,\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\frac 12$. Choose $x=(x_1,x_2)$ on the unit circle (say $(3/5,4/5)$). Then the integrals on the right are finite but the integral on the left diverges (you basically integrate inverse distance to $x$). Perhaps, you meant something else?

Comment: Yes. I agree. I hope you allow me to edit the question. I am sorry I was sloppy. My intention to show that the estimate is correct for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

Comment: As you pointed out, the constant in the inequality $(*)$ must depend on $x_1,\dots,x_{N}$.